# How to implement navigation with a TreeView instead of a Tabber in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation

Imagine a `Tabber` in WPF with multiple tab pages. Now I would like to use a `TreeView` for navigation and **not** the TabPages.

The `TreeView` toggles between the content pages, without deleting and re-creating them.

**How is this implemented?**

Should there still be a `Tabber` with hidden TabPages or is there a different approach? What's the canonical way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this in many applications and seems to be correct and nonMVVM breaking. Maybe that is what you are looking for:

```
public class ShellViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ICommand _changeViewModelCommand;

        private object _currentViewModel;
        private List<object> _viewModels = new List<object>();

        public ShellViewModel()
        {
            ViewModels.Add(new HomeViewModel());
            CurrentViewModel = ViewModels[0];
        }

        private void ChangeViewModel(object viewModel)
        {
            if (!ViewModels.Contains(viewModel))
                ViewModels.Add(viewModel);

            CurrentViewModel = ViewModels.FirstOrDefault(vm => vm == viewModel);
        }
    }
```

And the view:

```
<Grid Margin="20">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Header -->
    <TextBlock Text="Application Name" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="24" />

    <Line Grid.Row="1" Stroke="Black" Margin="0,5" StrokeThickness="1" Stretch="Fill" X2="1" />
    <!-- Content -->
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
</Grid>
```

Thanks to [Rachel Lim's Blog](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/07/17/navigation-with-mvvm/)

I know this is not using a TreeView, but maybe it will fit your necesities. Hope it helps.

Comment: So the `ContentControl.Content` can be bound to a `UserControl` in code behind?

Comment: Just tried it. Simple and **exactly** what I was looking for! +1

Comment: I was afraid of giving a complete diferent solution. Glad it helps ^^